# The task sometimes stay "locked"

Tags: javafx, task

I'm writting an application to manage sound in which I'm using many indicators and one of them is an indicator of "clipping".
The way it shall works is : if the sound level is going over a limit, a method called "setClipping" is changing the color of a circle (called "clip" in the code below) to turn it from a dark red to red.
When this indicator is turned to red, it stays red for 500 ms and then, goes back to dark red.
While the indicator is red, if the method "setClipping" is called again, the task is cancelled ; and then, a new one is builded and started.

Here is the code of the method :

```
public void setClipping(boolean clipping) {
// The Task "task" and Circle "clip" are declared earlier in my class

    if (clipping) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if (task!=null && task.isRunning()) {
                task.cancel();
            }
        });
        task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Going red !");
                clip.setFill(Color.RED);
                try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                System.out.println("Back to dark...");
                clip.setFill(Color.RED.interpolate(Color.RED, 0.5));
                return null;
            }

        };
        new Thread(task).start();

    }
}
```

The bug is : sometimes, the "clip circle" is not changing color when the task ends and yet, the "System.out.println(...)" methods are called.
What's wrong in my code and what tips would you give me to solve my problem ?

Comment: you _must not_ change nodes in the scenegraph off the fx-app thread

Comment: @kleopatra So, shall I only change a kind of flag and let the fx-thread reading this flag to make the change ?

Comment: can't say without an [mcve]

Comment: @kleopatra I finally found a solution with a timeline. My IHM contains a timeline to "delay" too frequent updates and maintain a kind of 50 fps refreshing. So, at each refreshing - and a 20ms period of refreshing is enough for my needs - I check the "clipping" flag and update my clip appearance. Nevertheless, thank you for your help.

Comment: glad you found a solution :) Please consider to post an answer such that future readers can profit from it.